# Load all function with use-package

Tags: use-package

How to load all function in package with use-package ?

I modified [crux](https://github.com/bbatsov/crux/blob/master/crux.el) package, and make my own `simple-crux.el`

Inside `simple-crux.el`, say I have function `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

when I use

```
(use-package simple-crux
  :load-path "~/.emacs.d/somewhare"
  :bind ("C-c w" . foo))
```

I only have `foo` function loaded when emacs start. I have all three function, only after I invoke `C-c w` (foo function)

I can have all three function loaded after emacs start using `(require 'simple-crux)`, but it is different case.

**Things that make me confused**

- why `use-package` only load function mentioned in `:bind`, and other functions are loaded after the specified binding invoked (in my simple-crux.el). even I have add `###autoload` on the top of every function.
- But why I can have all function from `helm`, `magit`, etc. even I don't hook them to emacs startup nor I don't invoke their specified binding. (with the same use-package scheme as my simple-crux.el)

```
  (use-package magit
    :ensure t
    :bind ("C-c g" . magit-status))
```

Comment: If you want to autoload other commands you can use `:commands` keyword. The reason that commands from other packages are autoloaded is that you probably installed them with package manager which loads them for you in `package-initialize`.

Answer (score 2):

You can load all function from packages in `use-package` using `:demand` keyword.

as mention [here](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package)

> You can override package deferral with the `:demand` keyword. Thus, even
>   if you use `:bind`, using `:demand` will force loading to occur
>   immediately and not establish an autoload for the bound key.

After trying `:demand`, I have all my function from `simple-crux.el` loaded in emacs startup.

I also tried to install `crux` using `use-package` as follow

```
(use-package crux
  :ensure t)
```

And I get all crux functions loaded after emacs start, *probably* as what [mkcms comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39067/load-all-function-with-use-package?noredirect=1#comment61662_39067)

> The reason that commands from other packages are autoloaded is that
>   you probably installed them with package manager which loads them for
>   you in `package-initialize`

**but the mysterious** thing happened again. I try to put `:demand` in `magit`

```
(use-package magit
  :ensure t
  :demand)
```

But I still can't get all `magit` function loaded. e.g I can't find `magit-bookmark--log-jump` function, but most of other function in magit (that comes with `###autoload`) are loaded.

```
;;;###autoload
(defun magit-bookmark--log-jump (bookmark)
 ......
```

**Update 1: 2018-02-26**

All the mysterious problem solved :) 
*(it's not mysterious, it's the lack of my knowledge)*

- When we use `:bind` only in `use-package`

Function that can be invoked trough mini-buffer is only function with `:bind`
(of course that function must have `(interactive)` )

- Using `:bind` and `:diminish` together

The result same as using `:bind` only

- Using `:diminish` without `:bind`

We have all the function with `(interactive)` loaded, and can be invoked trough mini-buffer, even that function does not have `###autoload` and `:bind`